# What is the intuition behind the rules of Hobbs Algorithm?

Tags: computational-linguistics, pronouns

I am trying to understand the Hobbs Algorithm. I am able to follow the algorithm and solve tree walking questions to find the antecedent of a pronoun, but I do not get the intuition behind the rules defined in the Hobbs Algorithm. Can someone please help me in explaining the meaning of these rules ?

> 1. Begin at the noun phrase (NP) node immediately dominating the pronoun.
> 2. Go up the tree to the first NP or sentence (S) node encountered. Call this node X, and call the path used to reach it p.
> 3. Traverse all branches below node X to the left of path p in a left-to-right, breadth-first fashion. Propose as the antecedent any NP node that is encountered which has an NP or S node between it and X.
> 4. If node X is the highest S node in the sentence, traverse the surface parse trees of previous sentences in the text in order of recency, the most recent first; each tree is traversed in a left-to-right, breadth-first manner, and when an NP node is encountered, it is proposed as antecedent.If X is not the highest S node in the sentence, continue to step 5.
> 5. From node X, go up the tree to the first NP or S node encountered. Call this new node X, and call the path traversed to reach it p.
> 6. If X is an NP node and if the path p to X did not pass through the Nominal node that X immediately dominates, propose X as the antecedent.
> 7. Traverse all branches below node X to the left of path p in a left-to-right, breadth- first manner. Propose any NP node encountered as the antecedent.
> 8. If X is an S node, traverse all branches of node X to the right of path p in a left-to- right, breadth-first manner, but do not go below any NP or S node encountered. Propose any NP node encountered as the antecedent.
> 9. Go to Step4

I have taken these rules from Jurafsky & Martin. These rules can also be found in [this paper](https://www.isi.edu/%7Ehobbs/PronounResolution.pdf) .

Comment: It looks like a step-by-step reconstruction of Langacker's dictum that a pronoun may not both precede and command its antecedent, with a metric for closeness.